# Rudin 6.10 but with countable discontinuities

Tags: riemann-integration

This is theorem 6.10 in baby Rudin:

> Suppose $f$ is bounded on $[a, b]$, $f$ has only finitely many points of discontinuity on $[a, b]$, and $\alpha$ is continuous at every point at which $f$ is discontinuous. Then $f \in \mathscr{R}(\alpha)$.

Is this still true if we're given that f has countable discontinuities instead of infinitely many? I've heard of Lebesgue criterion and how a function with a countable set of discontinuities is Riemann integrable but I'm not sure how $\alpha$ comes into play here.

Some definitions:

Definition 6.1:

> Let $[a, b]$ be a given interval. By a *partition* $P$ of $[a, b]$ we mean a finite set of points $x_0, x_1, \ldots, x_n$, where 
>   $$ a = x_0 \leq x_1 \leq \cdots \leq x_{n-1} \leq x_n = b.$$
>   We write 
>   $$ \Delta x_i = x_i - x_{i-1} \qquad (i = 1, \ldots, n). $$ 
>   Now suppose $f$ is a bounded real function defined on $[a, b]$. Corresponding to each partition $P$ of $[a, b]$ we put
>   $$
> \begin{align}
>  M_i &= \sup f(x) \qquad (x_{i-1} \leq x \leq x_i), \\
> m_i &= \inf f(x) \qquad (x_{i-1} \leq x \leq x_i), \\
> U(P, f) &= \sum_{i=1}^n M_i \Delta x_i, \\
> L(P, f) &= \sum_{i=1}^n m_i \Delta x_i,
> \end{align}
>  $$
>   and finally 
>   $$ 
> \begin{align}
> \tag{1} \overline{\int_a^b} f dx &= \inf U(P, f), \\
> \tag{2} \underline{\int_a^b} f dx &= \sup L(P, f),\\\,
> \end{align}
> $$
>   where the $\inf$ and the $\sup$ are taken over all partitions $P$ of $[a, b]$. The left members of (1) and (2) are called the *upper* and *lower* *Riemann integrals* of $f$ over $[a, b]$, respectively.
>
> If the upper and lower integrals are equal, we say that $f$ is *Riemann-integrable* on $[a, b]$, we write $f \in \mathscr{R}$ (that is, $\mathscr{R}$ denotes the set of Riemann-integrable functions), and we denote the common value of (1) and (2) by 
>   $$ \tag{3} \int_a^b f dx, $$
>   or by 
>   $$ \tag{4} \int_a^b f(x) dx. $$
>   This is the Riemann integral of $f$ over $[a, b]$. Since $f$ is bounded, there exist two numbers, $m$ and $M$, such that 
>   $$ m \leq f(x) \leq M \qquad (a \leq x \leq b). $$
>   Hence, for every $P$, 
>   $$ m(b-a) \leq L(P, f) \leq U(P, f) \leq M (b-a), $$
>   so that the numbers $L(P, f)$ and $U(P, f)$ form a bounded set. This shows that *the upper and lower integrals are defined for every bounded function $f$.* . . .

Definition 6.2:

> Let $\alpha$ be a monotonically increasing function on $[a, b]$ (since $\alpha(a)$ and $\alpha(b)$ are finite, it follows that $\alpha$ is bounded on $[a, b]$). Corresponding to each partition $P$ of $[a, b]$, we write 
>   $$ \Delta \alpha_i = \alpha \left( x_i \right) -  \alpha \left( x_{i-1} \right). $$
>   It is clear that $\Delta \alpha_i \geq 0$. For any real function $f$ which is bounded on $[a, b]$ we put 
>   $$ 
> \begin{align}
> U(P, f, \alpha) &= \sum_{i=1}^n M_i \Delta \alpha_i, \\
> L(P, f, \alpha) &= \sum_{i=1}^n m_i \Delta \alpha_i, 
> \end{align}
> $$
>   where $M_i$, $m_i$ have the same meaning as in Definition 6.1, and we define 
>   $$
> \begin{align}
> \tag{5} \overline{\int_a^b} f d \alpha = \inf U(P, f, \alpha), \\
> \tag{6} \underline{\int_a^b} f d \alpha = \sup L(P, f, \alpha), \\\,
> \end{align}
> $$
>   the $\inf$ and $\sup$ again being taken over all partitions. If the left members of (5) and (6) are equal, we denote their common value by 
>   $$ \tag{7} \int_a^b f d \alpha $$
>   or sometimes by 
>   $$ \tag{8} \int_a^b f(x) d \alpha(x). $$
>   This is the *Riemann-Stieltjes integral* (or simply the *Stieltjes integral*) of $f$ with respect to $\alpha$, over $[a, b]$.
>
> If (7) exists, i.e., if (5) and (6) are equal, we say that $f$ is integrable with respect to $\alpha$, in the Riemann sense, and write $f \in \mathscr{R}(\alpha)$.

Comment: I assume, $\mathscr{R}(\alpha)$ refers to the Riemann-Stiltjes integral w.r.t. $\alpha$, but this is not universal notation, and not everyone has the time or access to look into baby Rudin, so you might want to include a definition of that notation in your question.